# How do I convert a "pointer to const TCHAR" to a "std::string"?

Tags: c++, stdstring, tchar

I have a class which returns a typed pointer to a "const TCHAR".  I need to convert it to a std::string but I have not found a way to make this happen.

Can anyone provide some insight on how to convert it?

Comment: Create a new std::string with the returned TCHAR as initial value: TCHAR xyz=fun(); string convertedforme(xyz); ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on your compiling settings, `TCHAR` is either a `char` or a `WCHAR` (or `wchar_t`).

If you are using the multi byte character string setting, then  your `TCHAR` is the same as a char.  So you can just set your string to the `TCHAR*` returned.

If you are using the unicode character string setting, then your `TCHAR` is a wide char and needs to be converted using [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130(VS.85).aspx.).

If you are using Visual Studio, which I assume you are, you can change this setting in the project properties under Character Set.

Comment: Here is what I did:

#if !defined(UNICODE) || !defined(_UNICODE)

const std::string k_Var ( reinterpret_cast<char*> 
(Var2.ReturnsAConstTCHAR()));

#endif

Comment: Oops.  That should read "static_cast" not "reinterpret_cast".

Answer (score 3):

Do everything Brian says.  Once you get it in the codepage you need, then you can do:

```
std::string s(myTchar, myTchar+length);
```

or

```
std::wstring s(myTchar, myTchar+length);
```

to get it into a string.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the handy ATL text conversion macros for this, e.g.:

```
std::wstring str = CT2W(_T("A TCHAR string"));
```

CT2W = Const Text To Wide.

You can also specify a code page for the conversion, e.g.

```
std::wstring str = CT2W(_T("A TCHAR string"), CP_SOMECODEPAGE);
```

These macros (in their current form) have been available to Visual Studio C++ projects since VS2005.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you haven't defined `_UNICODE` or `UNICODE` then you can make a string containing the character like this:

```
const TCHAR example = _T('Q');
std::string mystring(1, example);
```

If you have are using `_UNICODE` and `UNICODE` then this approach may still work but the character may not be convertable to a `char`. In this case you will need to convert the character to a string. Typically you need to use a call like `wcstombs` or `WideCharToMultiByte` which gives you fuller control over the encoding.

Either way you will need to allocate a buffer for the result and construct the `std::string` from this buffer, remembering to deallocate the buffer once you're done (or use something like `vector<char>` so that this happens automatically).